# How to separate Hubspot scripts for mobile and for desktop in Drupal 9.5

Tags: hubspot, drupal-9

I am experiencing an issue with my Drupal 9.5 site, where Hubspot scripts are significantly impacting the pagespeed score of my mobile pages. Despite my attempts to use the Drupal Mobile Detect module to separate mobile and desktop resources, I have not been able to resolve the issue.

I kindly request your assistance in finding a suitable solution to this problem.

I tried using the Drupal 9.5 mobile detect module but was still not able to separate different resources(Hubspot Scripts) for mobile and desktop.